# Screen on laptop randomly goes black which messes up mouse

Tags: laptop, display, windows-11

I use an ASUS laptop that runs windows 11
More recently I've noticed that while using my laptop, the screen will go black for a split second and when it comes back on, my mouse is very pixelated. The only way it fixes is if I turn my screen off manually or the glitch happens again. It hasn't caused any other problems to my knowledge and doesn't interrupt my work. I'd just like to know what causes this and if it can cause other problems that might be more concerning. Also if needed how I could fix this

Comment: Try updating BIOS (UEFI) - take care, Power Driver and Video driver. Do a full restart and test.  Otherwise if not as aforementioned, get the machine serviced for a hardware error.

Comment: One reason would be a weak connection to the screen, with the problem caused by the vibrations from your typing. Is it the internal screen, or external monitor?

Comment: Thank you for your comment John I will look into that. harrymc it is an internal screen

Comment: This being internal strengthens the vibrations cause theory. For an external monitor it wouldn't have been relevant.

Comment: There may be a system diagnostic program you can run, either at startup, or after windows starts. You may need to find the manual on Asus' site.